# Cardinal numbers of right factors of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of a group $G$. The product $AB$ is called direct (and we denote it by $A \cdot B$, e.g., see [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2021.1884254?journalCode=lagb20)) if the representation of each element $x$ of $AB$ as $x=ab$, $a\in A$, $b\in B$ is unique (equivalently $A^{-1}A \cap BB^{-1}=\{1\}$, where $A^{-1}:=\{ a^{-1}:a\in A\}$).

**Question.** Let $G$ be a group and $A,B,C$ be subsets such that $G=A \cdot B=A \cdot C$. Then, is it true that $|B|=|C|$?

($|.|$ denotes the cardinal number)

**Discussion.** If $G$ is finite, then the answer is positive, since $|A \cdot B|=|A||B|=|A||C|$. If $1\in A$ (without loss of generality) and $A^{-1}A \subseteq AA^{-1}$, then we can define an injective (projection) map from $B$ to $C$ and also $C$ to $B$. Therefore, if there is a negative answer, it should be through infinite non-abelian groups $G$ (and infinite subsets $A$ with  $A^{-1}A \nsubseteq AA^{-1}$).

Also see [$AA^{-1} \subseteq A^{-1}A$ for every infinite subset $A$ of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713207/aa-1-subseteq-a-1a-for-every-infinite-subset-a-of-g) .

Comment: It is not true that $|AB|=|A||B|$, what it is realy true is that $|AB|=\frac{|A||B|}{|A\cap B|}$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469369/showing-that-lvert-h-k-rvert-frac-h-k-h-cap-k?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: -@Marcus The intersection is a singleton (because the product is direct).

Comment: right, in that case is true, but you have to say it in the question. Also, in this case $|A||B|=|A||C|$ and then $|B|=|C|$

Comment: The notation $A\cdot B$ means the product is direct.

Comment: then? What is the problem? It is just a one line solution

Comment: @Marcos: Not in the infinite case. If $|A|$ is infinite, then $|A||B|=\max\{|A|,|B|\}$. In principle, you could have an infinite $A$ and two finite $B$ and $C$ of distinct size with $|A||B|=|A||C|$. Likewise, you could have all three infinite, with $|A|$ of cardinality strictly larger than both $B$ and $C$, but with $|B|\neq|C|$. As to "saying it in the question", it says so in the question, prominently and at the top. The question also says the case of $G$ finite is trivial. Are you reading the question before declaring it trivial?

Comment: Please see the discussion. We need an explicit example, do you have any?

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand Who are you addressing? Please use the `@` if you are replying to a particular user.

Comment: Sorry, ok, @Marcos.  Did you see the discussion?

Comment: That’s probably far too elementary an attempt, but there are natural maps $f:  B \rightarrow C$ and $g: C \rightarrow B$ (where $b \in Af(b)$, $c \in Ag(b)$, so that $b \in AAg(f(b))$… which may not be enough. That kind of manipulations also show that if $A^{-1} \cdot B$ is direct, then $f$ is injective. (Thus if $A^{-1}\cdot B$ and $A^{-1} \cdot C$ are direct, then $f,g$ are injective thus $|B|=|C|$).

Comment: Isn't this [the same question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234538/cardinality-of-factors-of-infinite-non-abelian-groups/234614) that you asked, and was answered, on MathOverflow a few years ago?

Comment: -@Jeremy Rickard.  Oh yes, that's right. I forgot it. Thanks.